# Perturbation of eigenvalues of Schrodinger Operator.

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

Suppose I have a sequence of Schrodinger opertors
$$
T_n=-\Delta +V_n
$$
acting on (a subdomain of) $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Suppose that I view them as perturbations of the operator
$$
T=-\Delta+V
$$
where $V_n$ and $V$ are such that $T_n$ and $T$ all have compact resolvent (and for simplicity the potentials are real valued). Is there a way of bounding the difference in the eigenvalues of $T$and $T_n$ in terms of some non trivial norm of $V-V_n$, say the $L^1$ norm?

Could something be done in the less general case if all the potentials are positive?

Comment: Relevant: [Kato, p.214](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/kato1.pdf) ?

Comment: The difficulty with that approach is (as far I can tell) it would give a bound on the perturbation in terms of $\left\|V-V_n\right\|_{\infty}$ which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: I think what I am after is something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lieb%E2%80%93Thirring_inequality but for perturbations of Schrodinger operators with compact resolvent.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "all the potentials are positive". Do they go to $0$ at $\infty$ ? Then they would not have discrete eigenvalues ([with somewhat pathological exceptions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/350394/85443) ).

Comment: I assume that $V_n\geq 0$ and $V_n(x)\rightarrow\infty$ as $\left\|x\right\|\rightarrow\infty$ (this implies compact resolvent) as well as continuity. Hence $V_n\notin L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ but I would be interested if the perturbation satisfies $V-V_n\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ whether anything can be said.

Comment: Let $T$ be the 1D harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian and $\lambda U \approx V-V_n$. Since the eigenfunctions of $T$ are known, you might be able to "say something" using first order perturbation theory on $T+\lambda U$. There is [information on the $L^p$ norms of Hermite functions](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.66.7071&rep=rep1&type=pdf), could that be used?

Comment: My point is to try to construct a counterexample in the explicit case, with some norm of $U$ small but the first order perturbation term large. If you could do that, I think it would break your hypothesis for that norm.